# Can't get REGEX to work ((?=(<\/))(.*?)(?:\>))

Tags: regex

I have the following regex and it finds a partial solution for me:

```
((?=(<\/))(.*?)(?:\>))
```

Given the Following line:

```
</EventSubType><OrgUnitNm>###</OrgUnitNm></test:CommonAttributes><ProductArrangementBasic><ProductId>####</ProductId></part:Asking>
```

The regex will give me:

```
</EventSubType></OrgUnitNm></test:CommonAttributes></ProductId></part:Asking>
```

I want just:

```
</test:   </part:
```

Any help would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: don't parse xml/html with regexes. use a DOM engine.

Comment: The answer of this post will really help! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: You explicitly require any chars up to the `>`. Try `<\/\w+:`

Comment: Thing is that the string coming in is not a valid XML format. And I need to regex it to fix the errors.

Comment: Wiktor thank you!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: if you are parsing HTML, you'd better use a dedicated library for that.

I suspect you are using the regex with PCRE `/U` tag, like [`/((?=(<\/))(.*?)(?:\>))/U`](https://regex101.com/r/cH8qE6/1).

If you want to obtain just `</test:` and `</part:`, you may use a much simpler regex:

```
/<\/\w+:/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cH8qE6/2)

**Details**:

- `<` - a literal `<`
- `\/` - a literal `/`
- `\w+` - 1 or more chars from `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` ranges
- `:` - a literal `:`.